# UItextView dynamiclly Height and Link reconizer iOS 6 vs ios 7

Tags: ios6, ios7

I develop an application and I need to display the content using an `UITextView` which must have set the height dynamically and it must recognize a link.
  I used code above:

```
   self.textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n %@", self.offersObjects.body, self.offersObjects.url]; 
   self.textView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;   

   if (([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] integerValue] < 7)){ 
       CGRect frame = self.textView.frame;   
       frame.size.height =  self.textView.contentSize.height;contentSize.height;              
       self.textView.frame = frame;  
  }else{ 
       [self.textView sizeToFit];  
       [self.textView layoutIfNeeded];  
  }
```

My problem is that it doesn't recognize the link .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with below code :

```
-(IBAction)txtStustes:(id)sender
{
 NSError *error = nil;
 NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink
                            | NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber error:&error];

 NSString *string = self.textView.text;
 NSArray *matches = [detector matchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypeLink) {
        NSURL *url = [match URL];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    }         
}
}
```

Also add below code in your viewDidLoad method

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *LblProfileNameTouch=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(txtStustes:)];
[LblProfileNameTouch setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[self.textView addGestureRecognizer:LblProfileNameTouch];
```

Comment: Hello, I need open the link wenh user tap on that.Your code it's oky but it open the link automatically. If a put it on a method I can't detect the user tap on the link on the textview. I must 'create' e gesture reconier for this UItextView and after that open the link ?